# Batch Scripts - Alternative Output to Notepad?

Tags: file, batch-file, notepad

Good Afternoon,

Basically, I have a batch script that does the following:

- Pings multiple network machines
- Writes the result to a txt file
- Searches the created txt file for certain keywords, then outputs that to a separate txt file
- Displays the 2nd txt file

It's all very nice and lovely, basically if the machine pings fine then all it shows is the "Pinging xxxxx [10.xxx.xxx.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:" & "Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)" lines.

If it detects anything other than a good ping, it will report the error message in addition to the 2 lines above.

Which leads me to the question...

Is there an alternative output to notepad for the log file? The information that is displays is exactly what I need, but because it's pinging 20+ assets it looks extremely cluttered and ugly. Are there any decent alternatives to display the log file?

Apologies if this is a stupidly basic question, it's after lunch so my brain is only functioning at 0.01% of it's usual power...

Comment: Throw in some `echo.` statements to add blank lines so that the spacing is better. Software recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not necessarily after software recommendations, it's more that i'm asking if my only option to record a log file is as a txt file.

Comment: It will be a text file in the sense that it will be readable by a text editor, but depending on the contents of your log, you could maybe make it something like an xml or a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I made good experience with writing a .tex file and compiling it with latex (or its derivatives) into a .pdf file. Also, I use a bash script to write a .html document. An .xml file is a nice way to provide the data and an associated .xsl style sheet will add the appropriate visual representation.